# GET 200 request stuck in a loop

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I've created a "GET" route in express that saves data to my database and then uses puppeteer to create a pdf file from an ejs view template. The pdf is saved on the server.

When I make the get request my app saves the data properly and puppeteer correctly creates the pdf and saves it to the server. However the app then hangs in a loop making GET requests. Here is a screenshot of my terminal https://snipboard.io/uHZhco.jpg

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

```js
/* routes */
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const client = new Client({
    name: "Miley",
    surname: "Smith",
    boiler: "ideal",
    installprice: "fiver",
    pmhun: "forty",
    pmsixty: "thirty",
    pmtwenty: "twenty",
    fuel: "gas",
    location: "kitchen",
    orientation: "vertical",
    ladders: "no",
    scaffolding: "no"
  });
  client
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      res.render("pdf", { data: result });
    })
    .then((result) => {
      (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("http://localhost:3000", {
          waitUntil: "networkidle2"
        });
        await page.pdf({
          path: "quote.pdf",
          format: "A2",
          printBackground: true
        });

        await browser.close();
      })();
    });
});
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question on my part because I don't use puppeteer, but is this express app hosted at `localhost:3000`? Because if so, you've written a recursive loop right there in the code. Your client makes a request to `http://localhost:3000/` which hits the `/` route and renders the template, and then right afterwards opens a puppeteer instance at `http://localhost:3000/`, which hits the `/` route and renders the template, and then opens a puppeteer instance at `http://localhost:3000/`, which will hit the `/` route and render the template, and.... you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. I guess I need to somehow pass the template into puppeteer as a file instead of a url link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but what about adding finally() at the end of your code. [Link to article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

Comment: again, I'm not the most knowledgeable, but thought this might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding res.end() at the end of your .then block.